# Why does Jenkins running on aws instance keep failing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, tosca

I have a Jenkins running on AWS instance with Ubuntu server. Jenkins can’t reach the WSDL file on the remote server. The WSDL is running on the virtual environment (windows 10).

What can I do to solve this issue?

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ToscaCI
[ToscaCI] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins494407163776032501.sh
+ java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/ToscaCIJavaClient.jar -e http://18.233.94.164:8732/TOSCARemoteExecutionService/ -c /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ToscaCI/result.xml -t junit
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://18.233.94.164:8732/TOSCARemoteExecutionService//?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Connection timed out (Connection timed out).
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at org.tempuri.RemoteExecutionService.<init>(RemoteExecutionService.java:43)
    at com.tricentis.continuousintegration.toscacijavaclient.Dispatcher.Connect(Dispatcher.java:30)
    at com.tricentis.continuousintegration.toscacijavaclient.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:984)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:385)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:216)
    ... 12 more
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@506e1b77
Message: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://18.233.94.164:8732/TOSCARemoteExecutionService//?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Connection timed out (Connection timed out).
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: http://18.233.94.164:8732/TOSCARemoteExecutionService//?wsdl not able to access this file. is it accessbile by jenkins server?

Comment: Is the URL to the WSDL right ??